# Calling instance's multiple inherited method named as middle inherited object

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have an `x` class with `y` static method:

```cpp
class x{
    public: static void y(){};
};
```

I have a `y` class that inherits from `x`;
I have a `z` class that inherits from `y`:

```cpp
class y :public x{};
class z :public y{};
```

I can call multiple inherited method `y` from `z` object:

```cpp
z::y();
```

However calling same `y` method from `a` instance of `z` thows `invalid use of 'y::y'` error:

```cpp
z a; a.y();
```

Why `.y` is treated as constructor if `y` class was middle inherited?

Comment: With `a.y()` you try to call the *non-static member function* `y` in the `a` object. Only if there's no `y` member function the static `y` function will be called.

Comment: Don't use instance invocation syntax to invoke static methods. It's silly.

Comment: But when I inherit to `z` directly from `x`, it works well. What is exact reason, that inheritance through `y` causes the error?

Comment: @Benio Please reread the comments. The answer to your question is already there.

Comment: So there is a `y` member function, but my question is why? Is `y` constructor of `y` class inherited and considered a member function?

Comment: Constructors are also member functions.

Comment: Oh, I didn't knew that. Thank you very much. It explains everything.

Comment: You can still call it. You just need to qualify it `a.x::y();`. But then it's even sillier, since you can just call `x::y();` directly.